# Symfony2 Upload, View, Update, Remove file

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have two entities: Ad and AdPhoto. I want use some functional like: upload, view, update and remove photos. For example I creating new Ad where I adding 5 images. After I want to edit this and remove some images from ad or update existed images.

On Ad form type I use collection of `FileType` field.

```
$builder->add('photos', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => FileType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => 'form.ad_base.label.photos',
                'translation_domain' => 'forms'
            ));
```

When I edit form, I want view Photo and File field(for image update) and Remove photo by clicking on [X] on the left of image.

Logic:
If new file is selected - replace old file.
If clicked on [X], remove container with image, file filed and button form page and after form submit remove that file from file system and database.

But how I can identify removed file I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Collection Form Type in Symfony is a bit tricky.

I would use collection of Image class (not FileType class) in form without add functionality, following closely the cookbook here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html, and when deleting is working, i would add extra field of FileType class for uploads.

The other possibility is to use for example https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and add custom ajax hooks for deleting images.